# Swift packages: sharing internal code between libraries but not library users

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

How should I share code between modules (targets in Swift package terms) defined in `Package.swift` while still exposing APIs from the shared code to library users? Another way to phrase this question is: How to share `internal` API in module with specific other modules (other libraries) but not library users.

For example, say I have 2 libraries, **Human** and **Dog**, and users only need 1 of them (or use both if they want). I came up with 2 approaches:

- I could make another library, **Core**, which contains public APIs that should be shared to library users (of **Human** and **Dog**), and use a separate internal library **Internal**.

  - This prevents setting access control for entities (methods, enums, classes, etc) in each file separately, to avoid overexposing things in **Core** which might not be able to go into **Internal**. This is because I always need to set the entities to public for access in Human or Dog, meaning they'll be public to library users too.
  - Library users who want to use library **Human** will also have to know to import both **Human** and **Core** to their Xcode project/ source files.
- Explicitly add the shared code directories to both targets instead of 1, using `target(sources:)` documented [here](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#target). This actually throws an error if 1 source file is shared between 2 targets: `target 'Library Human' has sources overlapping sources`.

I think the 2nd option is better but it doesn't work. Perhaps there is a better option I don't know about?

The reason why they need to be in separate modules is because one (**Human**) depends on a rather large dependency which should not be required for **Dog**.

---

I originally posted this on Swift forums [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-packages-sharing-code-between-libraries-while-exposing-some-apis-from-the-shared-code/49605), and will update here with a solution if I found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing the first method I listed in the question (4 modules):

- **Core:** Code shared by library A and B, which should be importable by the user.
- **Internal:** Code that library users should **not** be able to import. Depends on Core. Also depends on other libraries which shouldn't be exposed to the library user.
- **Library A** (e.g. Human): One library the user may choose to use.
- **Library B** (e.g. Dog): Another library the user may choose to use.

I then in Library A and Library B, I have a file called `Exports.swift` which has `@_exported import Core`.